# Anchor tag's onClick is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an anchor tag on the fly. It gets created, but for some reason the `onClick` is not working.

**Here is my generation code:**

```cs
HtmlGenericControl emailsubject = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
emailsubject.ID = count++ + "emailSubject";
emailsubject.InnerHtml = "Subject: " 
    + "<a id=\"summa\" href=\"#\" onClick=\"subject_Click();\">" 
    + results2["EmailSubject"].ToString() 
    + "</a>";
```

**Here is my `onClick` function:**

```cs
public void subject_Click()
{
    Response.Write("Clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it set up right now, you're trying to call a javascript function from an html element. Try either initializing the onclick function of the control you are creating or make use of another asp.net control (ASP:Hyperlink) in order to call functions in code behind.

Comment: Got it. Ya my bad. Now I got it. Thanks for your comment. How stupid am to do so. Thanks again.

Comment: Your welcome, and no worries it a simple mistake, we have all made them before.